# cross-tab conditional formatting based on column

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crosstab

I have a cross-tab in crystal reports with column representing transport line, rows showing dates and summary field representing TEU (its just numerical value). So I have something like this:

```
    L1  L2  L3 TOTAL
D1  10  5   0  15
D2  1   3   5  9
D3  3   50  17 70
```

Now I'd like to conditionally put background to the summary (numerical) field, but the condition depends also on the line. So in theory, after clicking on the summary field->format field->background->formula I'd put something like this:

```
select {@Line}
case "L1": (if currentfieldvalue >5 then crGreen else crRed)
case "L2": (if currentfieldvalue >10 then crGreen else crYellow)
case "L3": (if currentfieldvalue <8 then crBlue else crNoColor)
```

but for some reasons those conditions are completely ignored. I've even tried something as simple as

```
if {@Line} ="L1" then crGreen
```

but as above, crystal 2011 (14.06) ignores it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it finally using GridRowColumnValue ("@Line"):

```
select GridRowColumnValue ("@Line")
case "L1": (if currentfieldvalue >5 then crGreen else crRed)
case "L2": (if currentfieldvalue >10 then crGreen else crYellow)
case "L3": (if currentfieldvalue <8 then crBlue else crNoColor)
```

Source: http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=6798